# subtracting current year minus and return 1st january with result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in snowflake, How do subtract current year minus 1 and print as 1st january ( current year -1)?
this is sql query

```
cast( DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETSATE())-1,0) as datetime)
```

this should be converted to SNOWFLAKE

to be converted to Snowflake

```
cast( DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETSATE())-1,0) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
select '01/01/' || YEAR(DATEADD(year, -1, CURRENT_DATE)) as previous_year;
```

Comment: ok. Thanks though . it should return 01/01/2022 with timestamp

Comment: edited my answer, can you check ? and please can you edit your question and share the exact expected output